Sequence of rejected promise with Promise.reject()
I am learning microtask queue and i have a simple question.
With the following code:


Promise.resolve().then(()=>console.log("Resolved1 Promise"));
Promise.reject().then(()=>console.log("Resolved2 Promise")).catch(()=>console.log('Rejected2 Promise'));
Promise.resolve().then(()=>console.log("Resolved3 Promise"));
Promise.resolve().then(()=>console.log("Resolved4 Promise"));
Promise.resolve().then(()=>console.log("Resolved5 Promise"));



I expected output to be in the sequence:
Resolved1 Promise
Rejected2 Promise
Resolved3 Promise
Resolved4 Promise
Resolved5 Promise

But as you can try above, rejected callback is triggered in the last. Can anyone explain it to me?

Do you understand how promise chains work? Also have a look at the difference between .then(…, …) and .then(…).catch(…).

This is because you're chaining .chatch() to the result of .then() function. This can be fixed by removing .then() from the promise:


Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log("Resolved1 Promise"));
Promise.reject().catch(() => console.log('Rejected2 Promise'));
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log("Resolved3 Promise"));
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log("Resolved4 Promise"));
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log("Resolved5 Promise"));



Optionally, if you want to listen for both events, use a sigle .then() call to assign both listeners:


Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log("Resolved1 Promise"));
Promise.reject().then(
    () => console.log("Resolved2 Promise"),
    () => console.log('Rejected2 Promise')
);
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log("Resolved3 Promise"));
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log("Resolved4 Promise"));
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log("Resolved5 Promise"));




"having both .then() and .catch() callbacks." - or more precisely, having the .catch() chained to the result of the .then(). The catch method is not called on the promise created by Promise.reject(…) in the OPs code.

What are you calling "JavaScript's internal timings"? Since we're only dealing with already settled promises here there is no timing involved.

Code snippet:


Promise.resolve().then(()=>console.log("Resolved1 Promise"));
Promise.reject().then(()=>console.log("Resolved2 Promise")).catch(()=>console.log("Rejected2 Promise"));
Promise.resolve().then(()=>console.log("Resolved3 Promise"));



Output:
Resolved1 Promise
Resolved3 Promise
Rejected2 Promise

The output order is due to the following sequence of microtask queue operations:



Step
Microtask Added to Queue
Callback Executed
Output




1
Promise.resolve().then()
console.log("Resolved1 Promise")
Resolved1 Promise


2
Promise.reject().then().catch()
undefined (adds .catch() to the queue for step 4)
no output yet


3
Promise.resolve().then()
console.log("Resolved3 Promise")
Resolved3 Promise


4
Promise.reject().then().catch()
console.log("Rejected2 Promise")
Rejected2 Promise



When the rejected promise skips .then(), its .catch() runs in the next microtask after the first .then() but before subsequent .then() callbacks:


Promise.resolve().then(()=>console.log("Resolved1 Promise"));
Promise.reject().catch(()=>console.log("Rejected2 Promise"));
Promise.resolve().then(()=>console.log("Resolved3 Promise"));



The .then() method accepts two optional arguments: onFulfilled (for resolved promises) and onRejected (for rejected promises). In this case, the second Promise.reject() can have an explicit onRejected in .then() that prevents the rejection from propagating to .catch(). For more details on onFulfilled and onRejected, see https://promisesaplus.com/#the-then-method.


Promise.resolve().then(()=>console.log("Resolved1 Promise"));
Promise.reject().then(undefined, ()=>console.log("Rejected2 Promise")).catch(()=>console.log("Rejected2 Promise"));
Promise.resolve().then(()=>console.log("Resolved3 Promise"));



Here's another example that shows that it doesn't matter if it's the catch or then, the next then/catch will be added to the microqueue only after the previous then/catch executes.


Promise.resolve().then().then().then(()=>console.log("Resolved1 Promise"));
Promise.reject().then().catch(()=>console.log("Rejected2 Promise"));
Promise.resolve().then(()=>console.log("Resolved3 Promise"));




having both "Microtask Added to Queue" and "Callback Executed" in the same step makes that table very confusing. It looks as if the .catch() method itself was invoked only at the end.

@Bergi I've added an example at the end of my answer

Thanks, nothing wrong with the rest of the answer, but that table is still very confusing as it doesn't really distinguish the currently executing code from the callback that is added to the microtask queue
